# Adding a chart to a matrix, spanning it over several rows

Tags: reporting-services, charts, merge, rows

I have hit a snag in Report Builder 3 and was wondering if someone can set me straight.

I have a matrix that displays 7 important numbers by RevenueCategory, By Region, split out by month.

Works great.

I have each of those 7 numbers down in the Totals section to show how the Region overall is performing.

That works great too.

I added the line chart inside the Revenue Category as shown in the pic below.

THAT works great.

What I can not seem to figure out is how to get the same line chart added down in the totals section where I have drawn the big red "X" in the image below.  In the space where the existing line chart is, I somehow managed to get everything there to be one cell.  As you can see in the image, the same is not true in the total section.  It is 7 individual cells.  I do not get the option to merge those particular 7 cells (but I do get the option in the 7 cells immediately to the left of the red "X"...  it just looks bad if that chart is out of line with all of the RevenueCategory ones).

I have fiddled around with groups to no avail...  I am pretty new to SSRS, so I hope that I'm just doing something wrong and it can be done...  I'm not sure what else to try though.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!!

WELLLLLLLLLLL, crud....  After all that, I don't have enough reputation points to include my screen shot....  throwing this together and using numbers without any effort to make the math line up, so please overlook the numbers!

In a nutshell want a chart down in the TOTAL section, but I've managed to make that area 7 distinct rows that I can't seem to get back into one like happened when the Revenue Categories were grouped.

```
Region |   Revenue Category |                      |              |   Jan   |  Feb  |  etc.
   NW        Direct Sales        <working chart>       Net Sales      $100     $200       
                                        |              Budget         $50      $200
                                        |              Variance       $50      $0
                                   <same chart>        % to Budget    200%     100%
                                        |              Forecast       $100     $200
                                        |              Forecast Var   $50      $0
                              <bottom of same chart>   Forecast %     200%     100%
             ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             Internet Sales      <working chart>       Net Sales      $100     $200       
                                        |              Budget         $50      $200
                                        |              Variance       $50      $0
                                   <same chart>        % to Budget    200%     100%
                                        |              Forecast       $100     $200
                                        |              Forecast Var   $50      $0
                              <bottom of same chart>   Forecast %     200%     100%
             --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             TOTAL               Want a chart HERE     Net Sales      $200     $400       
                                 that spans these      Budget         $100     $400
                                 seven rows like       Variance       $100      $0
                                 it does above, but    % to Budget    200%     100%
                                 I can not get these   Forecast       $200     $400
                                 rows grouped into     Forecast Var   $100      $0
                                 a single cell!        Forecast %     200%     100%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey what you can do is add a group to both the rows in that tabel.

I think if you are using Report builder tool you can see "ROW Groups" at the bottom where you can see the group you created. Right click on it you can see a Add total field in it click on it .It automatically creates a row for the above columns with the addition of the data. Now run the report and you can see exact data. But i am not sure which tool you are using.

Comment: Akarsh, that was it!!!  Thank you so much!  I had manually added 6 of the 7 total rows (becuase it had automatically thrown one in on its own)...  The Add Total function added all 7 rows though and they are indeed merged in the right spot to add my chart!  Thank you again!